# Dapper: Converting a string to an enum

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I'm new to Dapper and I'm trying to figure out if it can handle mapping database strings to enums; it doesn't happen for me by default.

For example, say I use this SQL

```
select customer_type from customers
```

and this class

```
public class Customer
{
    ...
    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

with this enum

```
public enum CustomerType
{
     Unknown,
     SomeCustomerType,
     ...
}
```

In this case I always end up with the default enum value (Unknown) rather than a mapping of the string value from the database.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Edit:
I know that this is possible with an number field because an number will convert to an enum, but that has the drawback of having to ensure that the database id and enum are kept in sync. I'm looking for something similar but with string.

Comment: thanks, but I saw that answer already. It's really just a work around. I'd rather not have create a shadow property for every enum property I have.

Comment: Why not simply use a numeric column in the DB? Keeping them in sync is as easy as giving the enum values explicit values (even if its redundant) to avoid them from ever changing. That's also much less wasteful and easier to check for consistency than a string.

Comment: I'm working with a large codebase and database so this would be a lot of work. It also has the drawback of failing silently if they get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you alias the column name to have the same name as your property that should work too:

`SELECT 
   REPLACE(customer_type, ' ','') As CustomerType 
FROM customers`

You can also use the replace function to remove white spaces in case the values for the customer_type field in the database has any.